# ReferenceError: cordova is not defined @ng-cordova.min.js:7

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new in mobile app development.For learning purpose i build a app which scan the bar code and display the text.

**app.js**

```
var app  = angular.module('starter', ['ionic','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
});   

app.controller('ExampleController',function($scope,$cordovaBarcodeScanner){

  $scope.scanBarcode = function () {

    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function (imageData) {
        alert(imageData.text);
    },function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

});
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-panel>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1>Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <button class="button" ng-click="scanBarcode()">Scan</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-panel>

  </body>
</html>
```

When I press the button instead of opening the camera return this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to include ng-cordova.min.js file above the cordova.js file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title></title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body ng-app="starter">
    <ion-panel>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1>Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="ExampleController">
        <button class="button" ng-click="scanBarcode()">Scan</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-panel>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the ngCordova api through its service injection
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/statusbar/
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/keyboard/
in the run block since I believe the var you use doesn't exist.
Inject the service you use in the run block like you did in the controller.

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaKeyboard, $cordovaStatusbar) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $cordovaKeyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    $cordovaKeyboard.disableScroll(true);
    $cordovaStatusbar.styleDefault();
  });
});
```

And you may surround your controller scan call by $ionicPlatform.ready() since what you write in the controller can call scan low level function before it get ready.

```
$scope.scanBarcode = function () {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    $cordovaBarcodeScanner.scan().then(function (imageData) {
        alert(imageData.text);
    },function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: if you provide some code sample that would be helpful

Comment: why we need the cordovakeyboard plugin here

Comment: problem still exist :(

Comment: Concerning the cordovaKeyboard, since you use angular, and want to use the cordova keyboard plugin, you may use proper angular injection style to access the API. Better for writing angular tests.

Comment: this is the new error with the old one
Uncaught ReferenceError: cordova is not defined @ng-cordova.min.js:8

Comment: what command line are you using to test? And on which platform? ios? android? Because it will not work on any browser.

Comment: i am using windows 7 command line and im building the app for android

Comment: did you add the scanner plugin with "cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner.git" ?

Comment: yes i did. i am following https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/09/implement-barcode-scanner-using-ionic-framework/ tutorial

Comment: you may reorder your libraries import files in head, especially move up ng-cordova : 
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<script src="js/ng-cordova.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>

Comment: i am new in ionic.So i think i massed up little bit.I need your suggestions how to fixed this

Comment: Failed this time as well.